# Google maps detect buildings and demography

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

I need to detect if an arbitrary area in the map is populated or not.
I have think about two possible approach to try to resolve the problem.
I develop for android but if necessary i switch to javascript api.

Is there a way to detect if in a small area of the map are present buildings?
Or alternatively, would it better get a demographic data if available?

Any other ideas?
Eventually I have no problem to change map engine, like openstreetmap.
Thanks for attenction.

Comment: Google Indoor Maps which represents buildings are enabled by default in the [Normal map type](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#indoor_maps). As long as you zoom-in close enough, It'll show the buildings. So what do you actually mean? I'm not sure the demography features exists yet though.

Comment: Sorry maybe I did not explain well. I ask if there is a method to count the number of buildings visible from photo satellite, in an arbitrary and restricted area of the world map. I need this method to know how the area is populated.

Answer (score 0):

I've look around Google docs for this kind of feature and found none. It seems this is not yet supported at this moment. I even saw a similar [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/earth/czk6PtyVUHg) at google forums and the answer is also No.